# How can I get Linux Mint to show 3-d app switcher like in Windows 7?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, window-switching

In Windows 7 there was a setting to make `Windows+Tab` display a 3-d preview of every application and holding down the `Windows` key while releasing and pressing the `Tab` key would cycle through each application.

How can I get the same functionality in Mint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the Windows settings option through either the 'System Settings' or press the `Windows` key, type "windows" and select or press enter on the 'Windows' settings menu option.

Click the 'Alt-Tab' settings menu and select 'Timeline (3D)' for the Alt-Tab switcher style.

The only downside from the original Windows 7 (Aero, which actually launched with Vista) is that you cannot have both `Alt+Tab` functionality and `Windows+Tab` functionality with separate app switching settings. In Windows 7, `Alt+Tab` would retain the functionality similar to the 'Icons and Thumbnails' in Mint, as with previous Windows versions, and `Windows+Tab` offered the Aero Flip feature.